# How to make a field non-editable in Flask Admin view of a model class

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a `User` model class and `password` is one attribute among many. I am using Flask web framework and Flask-Admin extension to create the admin view of my model classes. I want to make certain fields in the admin view like `password` non editable or not show them at all. How do I do it?

I can make the fields not show up in the normal view but when I click on the edit button of any record in the table, all fields show up and are editable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should extend your view from ModelView and overwrite the necessary fields.

In my class it looks like this:

```
class UserView(ModelView):

    column_list = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')
    searchable_columns = ('username', 'email')
# this is to exclude the password field from list_view:
    excluded_list_columns = ['password']
    can_create = True
    can_delete = False
# If you want to make them not editable in form view: use this piece:
    form_widget_args = {
        'name': {
            'readonly': True
        },
    }
```

Hope this helps!
For more information check out the documentation:

- [Flask-Admin Documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Model View Documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#model-views)

Comment: This however also marks "name" as disabled in the creation form. Is there any way to only disable a field in the edit form?

Comment: You might want to use the `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled`. The latter causes the field to be excluded from the submitted form data, which may result in the field getting set to None/null depending on what backend you're using.

Comment: @blurrcat, I had the same question. Below is the solution I came up with.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to make field disabled for 'Edit' form but enabled for 'Create' form?

Comment: 'readonly' only works for text fields. 'disabled' will clear all values ( even relationships) !

Comment: Is it possible to clear readonly field ? in some case ? as it is on image upload field (it has clear button)

Comment: if user inspect the page and removed the read-only or disabled he will able to change the input value

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that expands upon Remo's answer and this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31965193/4403600). It allows for different field_args for edit and create forms.

### Custom Field Rule Class

```
from flask_admin.form.rules import Field

class CustomizableField(Field):
    def __init__(self, field_name, render_field='lib.render_field', field_args={}):
        super(CustomizableField, self).__init__(field_name, render_field)
        self.extra_field_args = field_args

    def __call__(self, form, form_opts=None, field_args={}):
        field_args.update(self.extra_field_args)
        return super(CustomizableField, self).__call__(form, form_opts, field_args)
```

### UserView Class

```
class UserView(ModelView):

    column_list = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')
    searchable_columns = ('username', 'email')

    # this is to exclude the password field from list_view:
    excluded_list_columns = ['password']
    can_create = True
    can_delete = False

    # If you want to make them not editable in form view: use this piece:
    form_edit_rules = [
        CustomizableField('name', field_args={
            'readonly': True
        }),
        # ... place other rules here
    ]
```

Comment: Great hack! But meantime it hides all the other fields on form. Do I have to  set them manuall inside form_edit_rules or there is another, more smooth way?

Comment: The only way I've found so far is to set them manually in `form_edit_rules`. Perhaps if you find an improvement, you can share it here :)

Comment: Quite a high ping for answer... :)
So actually, if no special rules for fields are required (as in my case), I finished up with just extending `form_edit_rules` by any columns list like `form_edit_rules.extend(column_list)`. And remove doubled one: `form_edit_rules.remove('name')`.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way to work the problem around is to use Flask-Admin ModelView method called `on_form_prefill` to set readonly property argument. According to [Flask-Admin Docs](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/?highlight=on_form_prefill):

> **on_form_prefill**(form, id)
>
> Perform additional actions to pre-fill the edit form.
>
> Called from edit_view, if the current action is rendering the form rather than receiving client side input, after default pre-filling has been performed.

In other words, this is a trigger, which is run when opening only Edit form, **not** the Create one.

So, the solution for the example used above would be:

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    ...
    def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
        form.name.render_kw = {'readonly': True}
```

The method is run after all other rules applied, so none of them are broken, including set of columns.

Comment: As readonly property is set inside method, we can apply it only in some certain cases, according to some other fields existing values, for example. That was the reason I had to find it after few months :D