# Flask Admin ModelView different fields between CREATE and EDIT

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

In a Flask app using Flask Admin I would like to be able to define different form fields in the Edit section of a ModelView than those in the Create section.

The `form_columns` setting applies to both Create and Edit, but I can't seem to find a way to give different sets of columns to each section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`form_edit_rules`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_create_rules) and [`form_create_rules`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_create_rules) to override form columns/fields.